# Pandas: Update if statement matches

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_Import.update(df_Import["QUALIFIER"].where(df_Import["TYPE"].str.contains("LM")), df_Import["QUALIFIER"]"Leistung")
```

I am trying to update the empty slot in my column `df_Import["QUALIFIER"]` if the condition, that the other column `df_Import["TYPE"]` contains `"LM"` inside.

But how can I tell my program to write "Leistung" inside the `["QUALIFIER"]` column if the condition matches?

Comment: Use np.where: `df_Import['Qualifier'] = np.where(df_Import["TYPE"].str.contains("LM"), "Leistung", df_Import['Qualifier'])`

Comment: `df_Import.loc[df_Import["TYPE"].str.contains("LM"),'Qualifier'] = "Leistung"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_Import["QUALIFIER"] = df_Import.apply(lambda x: 'Leistung' if 'LM' in x["TYPE"] else x["QUALIFIER"] , axis = 1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code